# Tkinter: Label lines of triangle (create_polygon)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have this python function:

```
def draw(a, b, c):
    A = (0, 0)
    B = (c, 0)
    hc = (2 * (a**2*b**2 + b**2*c**2 + c**2*a**2) - (a**4 + b**4 + c**4))**0.5 / (2.*c)
    dx = (b**2 - hc**2)**0.5
    if abs((c - dx)**2 + hc**2 - a**2) > 0.01: dx = -dx
    C = (dx, hc)
    coords = [float((x + 1) * 75) for x in A+B+C]
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_polygon(*coords, outline='black', fill='white')
```

I can enter *a*, *b* and *c* and a triangle is drawed by Tkinter.
So it looks like this:
[image]

**The problem**

Now I want to label the lines *a*, *b* and *c*. Like this:

[image]

And the label should **always** be in the middle of the lines.

[image]

**How can I do this?**

I looked at a lot of posts, but none is for dynamically generated triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more a math problem than a Tkinter question. You have the vertices coordinates, so you can compute the coordinates of middle of each edge. However, this would put the text on the edge instead of a bit aside. To offset a bit the text, you can do a barycenter between the middle of the edge and the opposite vertex, giving the x coordinates of the 'c' label:

```
xc = (xA + xB)/2 * (1 - w) + xC
```

If you take a slightly negative weight w, then the text will be slightly outside the edge, however, the offset from the edge is relative to the distance between the middle of the edge and the vertex. To avoid this, we need to divide the wanted absolute offset by this distance:

```
def text_coords(x1, y1, x2, y2, offset):
    d = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    w = - offset / d
    xt = (1 - w) * x1 + w * x2
    yt = (1 - w) * y1 + w * y2
    return xt, yt
```

(x1, y1) are the coordinates of the middle of the edge and (x2, y2) the coordinates of the opposite vertex. Then we use this function in `draw()` to add the edge labels:

```
def draw(a, b, c):
    A = (0, 0)
    B = (c, 0)
    hc = (2 * (a**2*b**2 + b**2*c**2 + c**2*a**2) - (a**4 + b**4 + c**4))**0.5 / (2.*c)
    dx = (b**2 - hc**2)**0.5
    if abs((c - dx)**2 + hc**2 - a**2) > 0.01: dx = -dx
    C = (dx, hc)
    coords = [float((x + 1) * 75) for x in A+B+C]

    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_polygon(*coords, outline='black', fill='white')

    xA, yA = coords[:2]
    xB, yB = coords[2:4]
    xC, yC = coords[4:]
    xAB, yAB = (xA + xB)/2, (yA + yB)/2
    xAC, yAC = (xA + xC)/2, (yA + yC)/2
    xCB, yCB = (xC + xB)/2, (yC + yB)/2
    dc = distance(xAB, yAB, xC, yC)
    db = distance(xAC, yAC, xB, yB)
    da = distance(xCB, yCB, xA, yA)
    xc, yc = text_coords(xAB, yAB, xC, yC, 10)
    xb, yb = text_coords(xAC, yAC, xB, yB, 10)
    xa, ya = text_coords(xCB, yCB, xA, yA, 10)
    canvas.create_text(xc, yc, text='c')
    canvas.create_text(xa, ya, text='a')
    canvas.create_text(xb, yb, text='b')
```

For instance, `draw(3, 4, 5)` gives:
[image: result]